# Multiple parameter Object type

Tags: c#, object

i have a enable and disable function in my program when determined the program is working... 
i wont the following parameter 'c' to be either Button, Label, or another Object that handles .Enabled

```
private void getWorkingChanged(Button c)<<--This is where i wont c to be multiple objects
{
    c.Enabled = !c.Enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base `Control` object has an `Enabled` property:

```
private void getWorkingChanged(Control c) {
    c.Enabled = !c.Enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting any control then just do

```
private void getWorkingChanged(Control c)<<--This is where i wont c to be multiple objects
{
    c.Enabled = !c.Enabled;
}
```

if you want it to be of different object you'll have to create interface

```
public interface IEnabler
{
    void Enable();
}
```

and then do

```
private void getWorkingChanged(object c)<<--This is where i wont c to be multiple objects
{
    IEnabler ie = c as IEnabler;
    if(ie != null)
       ie.Enable();
}
```

but of course you'll have to implement your own Enable method for what object you want to do enable on your `getWorkingChanged` method

Comment: @DanielJones good to hear(accept simon's answer or mine if you've got your needed answer by clicking the "v" sign)

Comment: @DanielJones sry, no :), but you can +1 both of us

Comment: Sure, what is +1? sorry I'm kinda not use to this website!

Comment: @DanielJones the arrow above the number you see next to each answer

Comment: Thanks i have it now.